# ECW/MrSid plugin for GDAL from Kyngchaos not working on Mountain Lion?

Tags: gdal, osx, mrsid, ecw

Subject says it all. I have installed all of [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) packages, but

```
gdalinfo --formats
```

does not list ECW or MrSid formats.
Could someone else with Mountain Lion try if they can get *any* JP2 driver installed into GDAL?

Comment: (I always get the tumbleweed badge. :( Am I so weird? ;)

Comment: did you installed the [ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK Desktop Read-Only](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/other/ecw/erdasecwjpeg2000sdk/Downloads.aspx) ??

Comment: I'm using kyngchaos for years, never had to do this for the, I believe , statically linked binary plugins. (I'm not compiling anything) And, this requirement is not mentioned on the website, but then again it does not officially support Mountain Lion. So is this something that recently became a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.- [Install Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

2.- Download the [ECW/JP2 SDK from ERDAS](https://web.archive.org/web/20131009020839/http://geospatial.intergraph.com:80/products/other/ecw/ERDASECWJPEG2000SDK/Downloads.aspx) and install on /usr/local

3.- Install gdal using formula:

```
       brew install gdal --enable-unsupported --complete
```

Enjoy.

By the way, if in addition you want other things like filegdb, the steps are similar (i.e step 2.5 would be to download and install the filegdb SDK to /usr/local)

To clarify about the reasoning of why you don't see ecw/mr sid (or oracle client or filegdb or arcobjects driver etc etc) is because those drivers rely on proprietary SDKs. It has nothing to do with technical feasability and everything to do with licensing. When you download the SDK, you are agreeing to different proprietary licenses and those steps should not be legally skipped. That is why to get access to those drivers you need to compile them.

Your options are:

1.- to get the exact version of gdal used by kyngchaos (along with the dependencies - everything available different links from the kyngchaos site) and compile the ecw plugin as an external plugin. Then you would need to drop those binaries in the gdal-plugin folder (this is in fact what we used to do before utilities like homebrew existed). You can continue using the rest of the kyngchaos binaries.

2.- To get the binary from somebody that does all of 1.- and give you that binary. Highly unlikely since there are legal implications for redistributing something that you have not agreed to (depends on license terms). They would be legally involved/liable at that point if you violate the license in some way (for example, reverse engineering).

3.- Wait for the creator of the SDK (Erdas, ESRI, etc) to do this.

4.- Compile it yourself with something like Homebrew.

Personally, knowing this, I usually opt for . In the past, I used Kyngchaos a lot (and still do). Nevertheless, mixing kyngchaos binaries and homebrew can get you in trouble that is hard to debug/fix if you don't know what you are doing.

**Update:** realized it was not necessary to manually tweak the formula, so I made the steps shorter

**Update 2:** added explanation about licensing

Comment: While this works, it does add a bunch of other pain via homebrew.

Comment: @JayLaura what kind of other pain? I have completely replaced all my kyngchaos binaries with homebrew formulas since now you have one for everything

Comment: if you are running EPD,multiple virtualenv, python installs outside homebrew,64bit wxPython, etc. it can be a pain to get everything setup to communicate properly.  It requires some modifications to .bashrc or .bash_profile. Also wouldn't mix homebrew with MacPorts or Fink (in case the poster runs either).  +1 as your solution will solve the OP problem.

Comment: @JayLaura you are right about multiple virtualenv. But outside frameworks can potentially have the same problem :(.  Personally, what I do is create a "main" virtualenv that I activate when I do homebrew, so that one gets all the python libraries. When I need to "install" a library there, I soft link the packages that I need to the virtualenv's site-packages. Not ideal because of the extra steps, but works well with pip

Comment: It is the soft linking that find can be problematic.  In virtualenvs where I know I will need multiple relatively static packages (numpy, scipy, pandas) I create with the system site-packages and then override with `pip install xxxyyy=version`.  Either way works and neither is ideal!

Comment: While this is a very helpful comment in general, it does not really answer the question, to be stackexchange-formal. I am puzzled about the fact, that Kyngchaos not even mentions anywhere that things don't work for Mountain Lion (he only says he will skip it for a while),while someone must have told mentioned at least if things work fine there or not?Thing is, Kyngchaos' system worked for years for me without any prob and I don't want to give it up easily.(hence the reference to Kyngchaos in the question)

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye added explanation of why binary is not available and what your options are

Comment: It turned out that I had a clash of EPD's gdalinfo and the one coming from Kyngchaos. So, actually, my ECW plugin was indeed installed, just the wrong gdal was being picked up. I went and removed the incomplete gdal from EPD with "enpkg --remove gdal".

Comment: About: "Download the ECW/JP2 SDK from ERDAS and install on /usr/local". The link you provide has number of downloads, but I can find them for linux and windows (.exe files) only. Which particular one should work on OSX?